# How to prevent client from modifying the list object

Tags: c++, architecture

I faced this question in a company written test. The class goes like this:

```
class DB
{
ABC *list;
public:
ABC *getlist();
ABC *addlast();
ABC *remove(x);
ABC *freelist();
.....
}
```

Now the question is first to find any instance where the client can modify the list on its own. So the client can take the pointer by getlist and play with it or use ABC class API's to modify it more.

1. How to prevent the client from modifying this. What class architecture can be made which will not allow the client to do this.

Comment: Make use of an const_iterator to prevent from modifying the returned pointer..

Answer (score 1):

The devil's in the detail: what aspects of the DB API they expect you to retain.

The simplest approach is just to encapsulate `list` properly - still using your pseudo-code style...

```
class DB
{
    ABC list;  // I'd store by value unless there's a reason not to
  public:
    ABC getlist() const;           // only get a copy
    const ABC& getlistref() const; // another option...
    void addlast(x);
    void remove(x);
    void freelist();
.....
};
```

Other options include exposing the `list` using iterators (i.e. `begin` and `end` functions), or providing a `visit(VisitorFunctor&)` function to let the client code do something with every element in the list.